# Difficulty centering li element

Tags: html, css

I'm having difficulty centering `li` elements in my document.

I've put a wrapper (`<div align="center">` around the `li` elements but with little luck.

It seems to be only centering the header of each `li` element and not the entire block of `li` elements. I would like the whole block of `Priority, Round 1 and Round 2` centred (i.e. in the middle of a div).

This is my code so far: http://jsfiddle.net/nTcBk/

HTML

```
<div>
<div align="center">
<ul class="round">
        <li class="current-round" style="cursor: default; ">
          <div>Priority</div>
          <span>Ending 01/11/2012</span></li>
        <li style="cursor: default; ">
          <div>Round 1</div>
          <span>Starting 01/12/2012</span></li>
        <li style="cursor: default; ">
          <div>Round 2</div>
          <span>Starting 01/01/2013</span></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

​CSS

```
.round {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
.round li {
    color: #DDD;
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
.round li span {
    font-size: 12px;
    display: block;
}
.round .current-round {
    color: #2a145d;
    cursor: auto;
}
​
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enjoy- http://jsfiddle.net/nTcBk/1/
instead of:

```
.round {
    width:100%;
}
```

use:

```
.round {
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Too bad this doesn't work in IE6/7 because of the floating list elements.

Answer (score 1):

align attribute is meant for **tables** (and is **deprecated**). Instead of align="center" you can add a CSS class to your div
`<div class="align-center">`

Then in your CSS stylesheet you do:

`.align-center {text-align:center}`

Comment: Need to remove `float: left;` from `.round li` and add display: inline-block.

To work in IE7, add `*zoom: 1; *display:inline;`